# Would this work? I'm trying to make a multi-dimensional array, and I'm pretty sure it would work in Java, but I don't know about C++

Tags: java, c++, multidimensional-array

```
string months[3][12];
months[0][12] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", 
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
    "November", "December"};
months[1][12] = {"january", "february", "march", "april", 
    "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", 
    "november", "december"};
months[2][12] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12"};
```

If it doesn't work, how could I make it work, or how could I make it work better?

Comment: A better approach would we to use enums and not arrays at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign the internal arrays individually, but you can do this when defining the array:

```
string months[3][12] = {
    {"January", "February", "March", "April", 
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
    "November", "December"},
    {"january", "february", "march", "april", 
    "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", 
    "november", "december"},
    {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12"}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't. First, you can't use initializers outside initialization. You should try something like this:

```
string months[3][12] = {{"January", "February", "March", "April", 
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
    "November", "December"}, {"january", "february", "march", "april", 
    "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", 
    "november", "december"}, {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12"}};
```

Although, in new C++11 standard that's valid (with some changes), but only if you use `std::vector`. The second problem is that you try to assign an array to a string. Instead of `months[1][12]`, use `months[1]`:

```
vector<vector<string>> months(3);
months[0] = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"};
months[1] = {"january", "february", "march", "april",
    "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october",
    "november", "december"};
months[2] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
    "9", "10", "11", "12"};
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ is:

`int mat[][]={{1,2,3,4},
             {5,6,7,8},
             {9,10,11,12},};`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Make sure to read the FAQ to get to know the site. Posting answers that don't add anything to already answered questions is not considered very useful. You might want to start with unanswered questions.